# Magento cart not getting updated when POST through a JQuery ajaxSubmit

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento, form-submit

I have used ajaxSubmit for a very particular requirement. This ajaxSubmit will add products to the Magento shopping cart. Unfortunately even though I use return true; as call back shopping are page shows empty until I manually refresh the page from the browser button.

```
$('#nothanks').click( function (){
        $('#quickbuyform').ajaxSubmit(function(){
            return true;
        }); 
    });
```

Tried so many things including windows.location.reload(), nothing works, any help will highly appreciated

Thanx

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-product-to-cart-ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is what I did,

This is my JQuery submit,

```
$('#nothanks').click( function (){
var url = this.href;
$('#quickbuyform').ajaxSubmit();
    window.location.href = '<?php  echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>';
return false;
```

});

The real issue was $('#nothanks') was the Id of the image "Add to Cart", so that the return false rellay didnt work. it has to be the id of the href tag. like below...

```
<div class='pop_accessories_area_button'><a id="nothanks" href='<?php  echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>'><img  src='<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/prpage/nothanksbut.png') ?>' title='No Thanks Go to Cart' alt='No Thanks Go to Cart' /></a></div>
```

Problem solved!!

Thanx everyone for your support

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.reload();` after the ajax call to reload the page.

Comment: The fuction is window.location.reload() and not windows.location.reload() as mentioned in your post